# When I sign out with the OpenId Provider, I remain authenticated with the RP

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I've got a very simple DotNetOpenAuth implementation working for my MVC4 site (Google only).

The trouble is, if I (1) log in to my site using Google and then (2) log out of Google, I still remain authenticated on my site.

Is this by design? I'm new to OpenId so I'm a bit confused. Surely users will expect that if they sign out of Google that will end all their associated OpenId sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Is this by design?

Yes.

It would cause havoc for websites if other websites could just go and alter their session states when a user logs out of gmail (in this example). What if you were half way through executing a DB/SQL update script that requires the user_id from your session, and all of a sudden it's not there because the user just logged out of the gmail account? You'd have scripts falling over all over the place. Or what if they have 2 gmail accounts and log out of one account to check their mail in the other account. Bam, their logged out of all other sites. I think not :-)

When a user "logs in" onto a site using a 3rd party credential provider, it is still their responsibility to log out of both sites if they want to.